# Possible to add a nonArray property key with array literal notation?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have an array and then I add a non-array-index object property to it:

```js
let a = [1,2,3];
a['tobey'] = 'marguire';
for (let [idx, elem] of Object.entries(a)) {
    console.log(idx, '==>', elem);
}
```

Is there a way to do this directly with the literal notation, or does it need to be added separately using only dot/bracket setter notation?I suppose one way might be this, but maybe it doesn't make the intent clear:

```js
let a = {...[1,2,3], tobey: 'maguire'};
for (let [idx, elem] of Object.entries(a)) {
    console.log(idx, '==>', elem);
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run your "I suppose one way..." code?

Comment: Maybe using Object.assign would be a tad clearer? What's the need for this anyways?

Comment: @user1599011 it works, but then it doesn't have a `.length` and `Array.isArray(a)` is false.

Comment: @kellys just seeing how stuff works and dinking around with it a bit.

Comment: You can't expect `a` to be an array when you initialize it as an Object.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend this, but one way would be the following:

```js
const a = [1,2,3];
Object.defineProperty(a, 'tobey', { value: 'maguire', enumerable: true });

for (let [idx, elem] of Object.entries(a)) {
    console.log(idx, '==>', elem);
}
```